# How to generate fixed length random number without conflict?

Tags: java, random

I'm working on an application where I've to generate code like **Google classroom**. When a user creates a class I generate code using following functions

```java
 private String codeGenerator(){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String chars="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        int characterLength=chars.length();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            stringBuilder.append(chars.charAt((int)Math.floor(Math.random()*characterLength)));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

As I have 62 different characters. I can generate total **5^62** code total which is quite large. I can generate this code in server or user device. So my question is which one is better approach? How likely a generated code will conflict with another code?

Comment: Why not use UUID and convert to base64?

Comment: Failing that, use UUID and "base62" encode it.

Comment: Do the codes have to be restricted to a length of 5? How do you intend to use those codes? What would happen if you'd have a "conflict"?

Comment: @josejuan but my string length must be 5. How can I do that?

Comment: @Thomas yeah length must be of 5. I'll use this code for joining a class, so they must be unique. If any conflict occurs I tried to generate another code.

Comment: Btw, note that it's not 5^62 but 62^5 possible codes, so you only have about 900 million codes available - still quite large, depending on how many you actually need.

Comment: To clarify: Are the codes actually Google Classroom codes, or are they codes for an application similar to Google Classroom?  If the latter, why 5 characters and not more (say, 8 or 12), especially if a goal seems to be to make those codes hard to guess?  (Moreover, for the purposes of making hard-to-guess identifiers, `Math.random()` is far from suitable.)

Comment: @Thomas I have 5 places and 62 possible values. So 62P5 possible codes. As I can take same value twice so 5^62 possible code.

Comment: @PeterO. It's not google classroom code. My application has different groups, for joining a group you have to enter group code which is like google class joining process. Actually I tried to keep this joining code as small as possible.

Comment: No, you have a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of length n=5 over a set of k=62 elements. Thus the number of possible variations is k^n or 62^5. - To make it easier to understand: a byte is a permutation of length n=8 over a set of k=2 elements so there are 2^8 = 256 possible values (and not 8^2 = 64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment, it seems that you are generating group codes for your own application.

For the purposes and scale of your app, 5-character codes may be appropriate.  But there are several points you should know:

- Random number generators are not designed to generate unique numbers.  You can generate a random code as you're doing now, but you should check that code for uniqueness (e.g., check it against a table that stores group codes already generated) before you treat that code as unique.
- If users are expected to type in a group code, you should include a way to check whether a group code is valid, to avoid users accidentally joining a different group than intended.  This is often done by adding a so-called "checksum digit" to the end of the group code.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785210/random-string-unique-in-database-table/56015816#56015816).
- It seems that you're trying to generate codes that should be hard to guess.  In that case, `Math.random()` is far from suitable (as is `java.util.Random`) — especially because the group codes are so short.  Use a secure random generator instead, such as `java.security.SecureRandom` (fortunately for you, its security issues were addressed in Android 4.4, which, as I can tell from a comment of yours, is the minimum Android version your application supports; see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035165/does-the-android-gradle-lint-error-weak-rng-still-need-to-be-considered/55046334)).  Also, if possible, make group codes longer, such as 8 or 12 characters long.

For more information, see [Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers).

---

Also, there is another concern.  There is a serious security issue if the 5-character group code is the only thing that grants access to that group.  Ideally, there should be other forms of authorization, such as allowing only logged-in users or certain logged-in users—

- to access the group via that group code, or
- to accept invitations to join the group via that group code (e.g., in Google Classroom, the `PERMISSION_DENIED` error code can be raised when a user tries to accept an invitation to join a class).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to avoid duplicates in your scheme is to keep a copy of the ones that you have already generated, and avoid "generating" anything that would result in a duplicate. Since 5^62 is a lot, you could simply store them on a table if using a database; or on a hashset if everything is in-memory and there is only one instance of the application (remember to save the list of generated IDs to disk every time you create a new one, and to re-read it at startup).

The chances of a collision are low: you would need to generate around `5^(62/2) = 5^31 ~= 4.6E21` really-random identifiers for a collision to be more likely than not (see [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)) - and it would take a lot of space to store and check all those identifiers for duplicates to detect that this was the case. But such is the price of security.

Answer (score 0):

*Que:* A sack contains a blue ball and a red ball. I draw one ball from the sack. What are the chances it is a red ball?

*Ans:* 1/2

---

*Que:* I have a collection of 5^62 unique codes. I choose one code from the collection. What are the chances that it is "ABCDE"?

*Ans:* 1/(5^62)

**NOTE:** Random number generators are not [actually random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963778/how-random-is-math-random-in-java-across-different-jvms-or-different-machines).

Comment: Thanks. But all different codes are not available to me like a sack of balls. So I think second probability calculation is not as simple as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case you need a unique generator, what about the following. This is definitely not a random, but it's definitely unique for one instance.

```
public final class UniqueCodeGenerator implements Supplier<String> {

    private int code;

    @Override
    public synchronized String get() {
        return String.format("%05d", code++);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Supplier<String> generator = new UniqueCodeGenerator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(generator.get());
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually I'm developing an Android app, my minimum SDK is 19, for using `Supplier`  it's required to use minimum SDK 24.

Comment: Just remove ‘Supplier’